# MacVim caught deadly signal

Tags: text-editor, macvim

When I start MacVim within terminal I get a nasty error message saying it has caught a deadly singal SEGV. I really don't know what's going on. Like wise when I start the application by double clicking it on my Doc the app opens but I can't do anything.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 17):

I have had the same problem, and traced it to the Command-T plugin containing native extensions that were compiled against a different version of Ruby (1.8) to the one in my environment (1.9).

I recommend disabling all of your plugins/addons, and re-enabling them one by one.

You might get more of a hint what's going wrong by running MacVim's vim process inside gdb (Xcode required):

```
paul@paulbookpro ~ ⸩ gdb /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim                                                                                                                         [11:20:55]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1705) (Fri Jul  1 10:50:06 UTC 2011)
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...Reading symbols for shared libraries ................ done

(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-61/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

Hopefully gdb will report some useful information about the segfault, and you can use commands like backtrace to get more data.

Good luck.

Comment: This was exactly the same issue for me. Disabling Command-T fixed it.

Comment: Same problem here - disabling the filetype plugin fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

Signal SEGV means "segmentation violation" and generally indicates a bug in the application. You can try reinstalling it, or contact the software vendor.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it. And Macvim is a open source editor that a lot of people use so contacting a software vendor it's not going to help.